# Why do I get different results iterating over dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have two functions that iterate over a dictionary for a scrabble type game. I don't understand why one doesn't work and while the other does using the test input. I have used pythontutor.com to try and find out why one of them doesn't get the correct output.
This function gives the correct output

```
def updateHand(hand, word):
    
    newhand = hand.copy()
    for letter in word:
        if letter in newhand.keys():
            newhand[letter] -= 1        
    return newhand
print(updateHand({'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}, 'hello'))
print(updateHand({'a': 1, 'q': 1, 'l': 2, 'm': 1, 'u': 1, 'i': 1},'quail'))
```

correct output:

```
{'h': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 0, 'o': 0}
```

and

```
{'a': 0, 'q': 0, 'l': 1, 'm': 1, 'u': 0, 'i': 0}
```

This function doesn't give correct output and I would like to know why:

```
def updateHand(hand, word):
    
    newhand = hand.copy()
    for letter in word:
       newhand[letter] = hand.get(letter, 0) - 1        
    return newhand
```

This is the output for this function the 'l' value should be zero.

```
{'h': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 1, 'o': 0}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting the same output.No issues here

Comment: What's the state of `newhand` when you reach the second `l`? What's the state of *`hand`*?

Comment: Which python version?

Comment: The latest python.3.8 ish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is the count of `l` in `hand` is not updated in the second solution.

Try this:

```
def updateHand(hand, word):
    
    newhand = hand.copy()
    for letter in word:
       # use newhand here
       newhand[letter] = newhand.get(letter, 0) - 1        
    return newhand
```

In you code, just track the status of `newhand` and `hand` when encountering `l`:

after first `l`: newhand = `{'h': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 1, 'o': 1}` , hand = `{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}`

after second `l`: since hand = `{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}` , so newhand = `{'h': 0, 'e': 0, 'l': 1, 'o': 1}` .

The key deference is that the count in newhand is override by data modified based on hand.

Comment: So with the letter l it just repeated subtracting one from 2 and not updating. Thanks